# How to skip (move up/down) within code in vscode by chunk? like in vim shift + ] or shift + [

Tags: keyboard, visual-studio-code, shortcut

I want to go up and down in my script by chunks and skip parts of the code without using arrow key and by single line. I know a shortcut in vim extension in vscode which is `Shift + ]` or `Shift + [`.

Is there a shortcut in vscode that is similar, or is there a way I can setup myself?

Comment: What defines the beginning and end of a `chunk`?

Comment: @Mark A function/method for example

Comment: What language are you using?  How are the functions or methods contained?